# proving convexity of dual function

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I've come up at a task which seems easy but I'm surely missing something or I might have got it wrong.

given the dual function defined as $f^*(x) = Sup_{y\in S} <y,x> - f(y)$,
And a strong convex and continuous function $f:S->\mathbb{R}$.

If I am given $g(x) = (-1/b)f^*(-bx)$.
How can I prove that $g(x)$ is concave?
 or in other words that $-g(x)$ is convex?
Would like to hear some ideas, I tried using Fenchel's inequality but it didn't add up correctly, I think I missed something here.

Comment: f*= sup(over y) < x,y> - f(y) it should be , but the text is removed dk why

Comment: The pointwise $\sup$  over an arbitrary collection of convex functions is a convex function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please remember to format your answer using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also be sure you follow the Forum rules to write a [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Pippo , I wanted to but didn't figure out how, sorry, will fix the question.
copper.hat does this automatically hold for -g(x)

Comment: If $f^*$ is convex then surely $g$ is concave?

Comment: @copper.hat why do u say f* is convex? it is a collection of -f(x). -f(x) isn't necessarily convex

Comment: For a fixed $y$ the rhs of the $f^*$ is linear (hence convex). Taking the $\sup$ over $y$ yields a convex function. This is standard.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_1,x_2$ be vectors and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ be nonnegative with $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$.
First, for any vector $y$, 
\begin{align*} 
\langle y,\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2\rangle - f(y) &= \lambda_1\big(\langle y,x_1\rangle-f(y)\big) + \lambda_2\big(\langle y,x_2\rangle - f(y)\big)\\
&\leq \lambda_1f^*(x_1)+\lambda_2f^*(x_2)
\end{align*}
Taking the supremum over $y$ gives
\begin{align*}
f^*(\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2) = \sup_{y} \big( \langle y,\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2\rangle - f(y)\big)
\leq \lambda_1f^*(x_1)+\lambda_2f^*(x_2)
\end{align*}
which shows that $f^*$ is convex.

Now let $b>0$. We show that $x\mapsto \tfrac{1}{b}f^*(-bx)$ is convex. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
\tfrac{1}{b}f^*\big(-b(\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2)\big) 
&= 
\tfrac{1}{b}f^*\big(\lambda_1(-bx_1)+\lambda_2(-bx_2)\big)\\
&\leq
\tfrac{1}{b}\Big(\lambda_1f^*(-bx_1)+\lambda_2f^*(-bx_2) \Big)\\\
&=
\lambda_1\big(\tfrac{1}{b}f^*(-bx_1)\big) + \lambda_2\big(\tfrac{1}{b}f^*(-bx_2)\big).
\end{align*}
This shows that your function $-g$ is convex, as requested.

Comment: Thank you, and very nice!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $f^*$ is convex follows immediately from the fact that "the supremum of convex functions is convex".

For each $y \in S$, the function $x \mapsto \langle y,x \rangle - f(y)$ is convex. Thus, the function
$$
f^*(x) = \sup_{y \in S} \, \langle y,x \rangle - f(y)
$$
is convex.

Comment: Is this not what I proved for him, @littleO?

Comment: @max_zorn It is, just a slightly different way of phrasing it.

Comment: @max_zorn I personally prefer a form like littleO's, because it's much more compact and concise. In particular: I try to avoid using the secant rule to prove convexity when I don't _have_ to because of that. One reason is that in more difficult cases it _can't_ be used; so avoiding it helps train you and the reader to consider the wider variety of approaches.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thank you. By the way, I think you work on developing Numba -- I love the fact that prange() works now in version 0.36.1 of Numba. I recently posted about it on stackoverflow here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47830250/1854748

Comment: I’m not a developer, just an enthusiastic user and colleague of the main developers! We sit in the same office which helps give me influence...

Comment: @Michael Grant: I like littleO's as well. But the fact that the question was asked shows that this is not an expert - thus it seems prudent to give the proof. Peace.

Comment: We’ll have to agree to disagree I guess, because it is precisely the novice that needs to be taught that most convexity proofs in practice need not start with the secant formula.